# Vaadin field group bind Enum with TextField or etc

Tags: java, binding, enums, vaadin, vaadin7

Im pretty new it Vaadin and I cannot make simple binding (i google alot)

I have Person class with some field for example Gender.
Gender - its typical java enum.

```
    fieldGroup.setItemDataSource ( new BeanItem<> ( person ) );
    fieldGroup.setReadOnly ( true );
    ....
    DateField field = new DateField ( "some_caption");
    fieldGroup.bind ( field, "geenger"); //property - "gender" field (type - enum Gender)
```

them Im receiving an exception:

```
Caused by: com.vaadin.data.util.converter.Converter$ConversionException: Unable to convert value of type model.Gender to presentation type class java.lang.String. No converter is set and the types are not compatible.
```

Can you please share your ideas how to fix it.

Comment: `DateField`?  did you mean `TextField`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you would have to create your own [`Converter<String,Gender>`](https://vaadin.com/api/7.3.7/com/vaadin/data/util/converter/Converter.html) and assign it to your `TextField`

Comment: good links: https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating%20your%20own%20converter%20for%20String%20-%20MyType%20conversion